# Finding the parents of specific elements in a flat array/tree recursively

Tags: javascript, recursion

I have a flat array that holds multiple objects (children and parents). Every object consists of an id, a parentId and a third value as a "conditionId".

What I want to do is to filter the array based on the conditionId and then find the parents, and the parents of the parents, and then those parents and so on, until I reach the "root-level".

I already have a recursive function that does exactly that:

```
function findParents (directory, children) {
    // creating an empty array to push the matching entities into
    const entityArray = []

    // looping through every entity in the directory
    for (const entity of directory) {

        // looping through every child of the children-array
        for (const child of children) {

            // checking if the parentId is not 0 and if the id of the entity matches the parentId of the child
            if (child.parentId !== 0 && entity.id === child.parentId) {

                // pushing the found entity to entityArray
                entityArray.push(entity)
            }
        }
    }

    let recursiveResult = []
    if (entityArray.length > 0) {
        // calling the function
        recursiveResult = findParents(directory, entityArray)
    }

    // returning the entityArray plus the result of the recursive call of this function
    const result = entityArray.concat(recursiveResult)

    return result
}
```

The only issue is that if any elements in the array have the same parent, that parent is found multiple times, and I would like to avoid that, since it means having unnecessary operations that could be avioded by simply checking if those elements have already been found.

Example of what should happen:

flat array:

```
const myArr = [
    {
        id: '1',
        parentId: '0',
        conditionId: 'apple'
    },
    {
        id: '2',
        parentId: '1',
        conditionId: 'apple'
    },
    {
        id: '3',
        parentId: '2',
        conditionId: 'banana'
    },
    {
        id: '4',
        parentId: '2',
        conditionId: 'banana'
    },
    {
        id: '5',
        parentId: '2',
        conditionId: 'apple'
    },
    {
        id: '6',
        parentId: '2',
        conditionId: 'apple'
    }
]
```

Children found by conditionId:

```
const foundByCondition = [
    {
        id: '3',
        parentId: '2',
        conditionId: 'banana'
    },
    {
        id: '4',
        parentId: '2',
        conditionId: 'banana'
    },
]
```

In the first function call one would pass myArr and foundByCondition as arguments.

The result should look like this:

```
result: [
    {
        id: '1',
        parentId: '0',
        conditionId: 'apple'
    },
    {
        id: '2',
        parentId: '1',
        conditionId: 'apple'
    }
]
```

but actually looks like this:

```
result: [
    {
        id: '1',
        parentId: '0',
        conditionId: 'apple'
    },
    {
        id: '2',
        parentId: '1',
        conditionId: 'apple'
    },
    {
        id: '2',
        parentId: '1',
        conditionId: 'apple'
    }
]
```

I tried to do add a if statement to check if the element has already been found once:

```
    const entityArray: object[] = []

    // looping through every entity in the directory
    for (const entity of directory) {

        // checking if entityArray already contains entity of the loop
        if (!entityArray.some(item => item.id === entity.id)) {

            // looping through every child of the children-array
            for (const child of children) {

                // checking if the parentId is not 0 and if the id of the entity matches the parentId of the child
                if (child.parentId !== 0 && entity.id === child.parentId) {

                    // pushing the found entity to entityArray
                    entityArray.push(entity)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but it returns true every time.

Comment: Can you mutate the objects? Just memoise the function by storing the parent references.

Comment: Do you mean to store only the parentIds instead of the whole parent-objects?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood the question. I thought you wanted to optimise the recursive call, which might have been possible with memoisation (and, actually, a different algorithm than what you currently have). But if what you're currently looking for is just to prevent duplicates in the result, a much simpler solution is to just make `entityArray` a `new Set` instead of an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the conditional you added was in the wrong place. Try this in the middle of the function:

```js
// ...
// checking if the parentId is not 0 and if the id of the entity matches the parentId of the child
if (
    child.parentId !== 0 &&
    entity.id === child.parentId &&
    !entityArray.includes(entity)
) {
    entityArray.push(entity)
}
// ...
```

#### Alternative implementation

This isn't the Code Review exchange, but here's an alternative, more [FP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) approach. I find chaining array methods like this can really help to make sense of things which would otherwise be nested `for` loops. This is almost certainly slower, but that's only really important if you're going to query huge datasets or be running this very frequently.

```js
const directory = [
  { id: '1', parentId: '0', conditionId: 'apple' },
  { id: '2', parentId: '1', conditionId: 'apple' },
  { id: '3', parentId: '2', conditionId: 'banana' },
  { id: '4', parentId: '2', conditionId: 'banana' },
  { id: '5', parentId: '2', conditionId: 'apple' },
  { id: '6', parentId: '2', conditionId: 'apple' },
];

/**
 * Return an array of all ancestors of the provided item in the provided
 * directory by following `parentId` properties up the hierarchy.
 *
 * The item with `parentId: '0'` is assumed to be the root node.
 */
function findAncestors(item, directory) {
  if (item.parentId === '0') return [];

  const parent = directory.find(i => i.id === item.parentId);

  return [
    parent,
    ...findAncestors(parent, directory),
  ];
}

console.log(
  directory
    // Filter the items down to the ones we care about
    .filter(item => item.conditionId === 'banana')
    // Map each item to an array of its ancestors
    .map(item => findAncestors(item, directory))
    // Flatten the array of arrays into an array of items
    .flat()
    // De-duplicate the result
    .reduce((output, item) => {
      return !output.includes(item)
        ? [...output, item]
        : output;
    }, []),
);
```

Comment: Thanks, worked perfectly, but could you explain why it works that way? In my mind this is the same conditional checking the same array, just in a different place.

Comment: @RawDough This isn't very useful, but I'm not honestly sure why it worked. My instinct was to place the array check right before the push onto the array. In my experience nested `for` loops like this get quite confusing quite quickly. I added an alternative approach to my answer which might help – sorry to re-do your work. It might just be what I'm used to, but a more functional structure helps me to follow the logic more easily.